Playing with summations in AR models
I was trying to see why equation 7 can be rewritten as equation 8 (I will provide the equations below). In the lecture notes of my time series course they just tell us this holds, but I can't seem to figure out why this holds.
Equation 7:
$X_t - \mu = \sum_{j=1}^p \phi_j(X_{t-j} - \mu) + Z_t$
Equation 8:
$\Delta X_t = \gamma_0 + \gamma_1 X_{t-1} + \sum_{j=1}^{p-1} \gamma_{j+1} \Delta X_{t-j} + Z_t$
where
$\gamma_0 = \mu(1-\sum_{j=1}^p \phi_j), \gamma_1 = \sum_{j=1}^p \phi_j -1, \;\text{and} \;\gamma_j=-\sum_{i=j}^p \phi_i \;\text{for}\;2 \leq j \leq p.$
This is my work up till now:
$X_t - \mu = \sum_{j=1}^p \phi_j(X_{t-j} - \mu) + Z_t$
Rearrange the terms
$X_t - \sum_{j=1}^p \phi_j X_{t-j} = \mu(1-\sum_{j=1}^p \phi_j) + Z_t$
We now use
$\Delta X_t = X_t - X_{t-1}$
to get to
$X_t - \sum_{j=1}^p \phi_j ( X_{t-j-1} + \Delta X_{t-j}) = \mu(1-\sum_{j=1}^p \phi_j) + Z_t$
This is equal to
$X_t - \sum_{j=1}^p \phi_j X_{t-j-1} - \sum_{j=1}^p \phi_j \Delta X_{t-j} = \mu(1-\sum_{j=1}^p \phi_j) + Z_t$
I now rewrote $X_t$ to get to
$\Delta X_t + X_{t-1} - \sum_{j=1}^p \phi_j X_{t-j-1} - \sum_{j=1}^p \phi_j \Delta X_{t-j} = \mu(1-\sum_{j=1}^p \phi_j) + Z_t$
Rearanging everything
$\Delta X_t = \mu(1-\sum_{j=1}^p \phi_j) + (\sum_{j=1}^p \phi_j X_{t-j-1} - X_{t-1}) + (\sum_{j=1}^p \phi_j \Delta X_{t-j}) + Z_t$
I can now see that the first term is equal to $\gamma_0$, but the other two terms I can't seem to figure out how I can continue.
Does anyone have an idea?
Thanks!

Hi:  It looks like you are trying to derive the augmented dickey fuller test. The problem is, as far as I can remember, the two expressions are not equal. The first expresssion, (7), is an AR(p) model for $X_t$. The second, (8), is a time series model for the changes in $X_t$. But note that (8) is really acting as a machine for testing whether $X_t$ has a unit root ( i.e.: Is it a function of it's previous value, $X_{t-1}$ where the coefficient is 1.0). The other lags of changes in $X_t$ is only there to pick up any extra explanatory power due the other lags of changes in $X_t$.

The lecture notes specifically state that when we subtract $X_{t-1}$ from both sides of equation 7, we get equation 8. You are right that this has something to do with the dickey fuller test, however I do need to show that these equations hold in the weekly exercises, so they should be equal to each other. Nonetheless, thank you for your answer.

Okay. My mistake and apologies.  I thought the lags ( the last term ) were just added in for the unit root test. The original paper by Dickey and Fuller ( maybe, 1974, JASA. I'm not sure ) might contain the details as far as the exact equality. It also, might be in Hamilton's "Time Series Analysis". I haven't looked at the material in a long time and it shows !!!!

This is what I was talking about but I don't know if there's a free copy. It may or may not have the derivation. https://www.jstor.org/stable/2286348. It is 1979 so I was 5 years off.

Thanks Mark, I have looked through it, but can't find the exact derivation. However, I have found some other useful things in the paper. Cheers to that!

Hi George: I didn't work out the details but I was thinking about this problem tonight while I was on the train. What if you write out the AR(p) model at time $t$ and call that Equation (1). Then, write out the AR(p) model at time $(t-1)$ and call that Equation (2). Then subtract equation (2) from equation (1).  I have a feeling that should lead to something useful or close to what you want. I hope this helps.

Hi Mark, you are completely right. That's the way to go here. After some tiresome attempts, I found the correct steps... Thanks!

I'm glad to hear it. I know it can take time but, when you have some, it would be helpful to write an answer to your own question for future thread readers.
